# Java Applet Not Loading on Webpage

Tags: java, html, upload, japplet

I am trying to upload a Java applet to my blog. I have uploaded the `.class` file to Skydrive servers. But When I try to open the page, I get error, `Class not found`. Here is the HTML code, Please have a look at it

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="JappletGame.class" codebase="https://skydrive.live.com/?sc=documents&cid=4a7b1121c6f69308#cid=4A7B1121C6F69308&id=4A7B1121C6F69308%21106" width="640" height="480">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the detail of error:

```
Java Plug-in 10.6.2.24
Using JRE version 1.7.0_06-b24 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Alfred
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the link to the page:
[My Java Applet Link](http://wingoku.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_27.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url for your codebase is on Skydrive and required a login. Be sure your applet can be called from the Internet directly.

Comment: No that is not the case, I guess. I uploaded the file to google docs also but still not working

Comment: Just be sure it's public cause I can't access to https://skydrive.live.com/?sc=documents&cid=4a7b1121c6f69308#cid=4A7B1121C6F69308&id=4A7B1121C6F69308%21106

Comment: Any recommendations where can I upload the file

Comment: Any site where I can upload this file?

Comment: I would suggest you picking a free web hosting http://www.google.com/search?q=free+web+hosting to host your file.

Answer (score 0):

Package the class as a jar and then try again

Comment: Export your project (from your IDE) to a jar file.